# Pushing Router Data to DIstributed Messaging System

Tags: networking, message-queue, distributed-computing, flume, apache-kafka

Query: Making an interface of router as the producer of kafka cluster.

Issue: My router's interface is trying to push the data to the port on which kafka is running. (by default 9092).

Q. 1 But can the kafka broker accept this data without a topic being created ?

Q. 2 Can a kafka consumer pull data without specifying a topic ?

```
      If yes, How ?

      If not, What is work around this and how can i achieve this ?
```

1st edit:

I just checked that Kafka broker configs have "auto.create.topics.enable" field. 
If i set this as true and send some random data on kafka's port without using "kafka-console-producer" command, will the kafka broker accept it?

Thank You.

Answer (score 1):

> can the kafka broker accept this data without a topic being created

By default Kafka broker is set up in a way that it creates topic if you're trying to push data to it and it does not exists yet. This behaviour is controlled by `auto.create.topics.enable` parameter (with `true`/`false` values).

But **broker cannot accept data without topic creation at all**. And yes, topic name has to be specified on a producer side.

> Can a kafka consumer pull data without specifying a topic

No, it cannot.

> If not, What is work around this and how can i achieve this ?

You have to somehow retrieve topic name, for example, by listing all topics through the api and picking proper one, or you can dig directly into zookeeper internals, though I would not recommend you to do that.

> I just checked that Kafka broker configs have "auto.create.topics.enable" field. If i set this as true and send some random data on kafka's port without using "kafka-console-producer" command, will the kafka broker accept it?

Of course not. Kafka uses [it's own protocol](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/A+Guide+To+The+Kafka+Protocol) to establish connection between producer and broker, broker and consumer, moreover, those messages are encoded specifically.

Comment: Actually a router just knows the ip address and port number of kafka broker. It sends the UDP packets and i want to consume them. But router can not specify the topic name while producing! Could you enlighten me on this?

Comment: It's a bit unclear what you mean by saying *router*. Are you referring to the [*network router device*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Router_(computing))? You're going to intercept traffic sent through it or what? What UDP packets are you talking about specifically? Kafka uses TCP as a transport. Flume does not have concept of router as well.