# Can Kafka brokers receive data without topics being created?

Tags: networking, bigdata, apache-kafka

I am trying to send data from a router to the kafka brokers. Since a router can only be configured in a way that it knows the IP and port number of the Kafka server. 
I do not want to introduce a layer of java to consume messages from the router because it will cause latency.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Pushing Router Data to DIstributed Messaging System](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24269571/pushing-router-data-to-distributed-messaging-system)

Comment: you're duplicating your own question, clarify previous one instead of asking new